# How Update data when user changed id value in entity framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

i have this class

```
public class person {
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Family {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

i use this code to update value

```
public void Update(TModel entity)
{
      _dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
       SaveChange();
}
```

... I want the user to be able to change the ID value if needed.

but don't work currectly Update when i change id value , because entity framework can't find my id ,

please help me, how i can do...

Comment: Simply, don't change the primary key of your table. Create a new column for whatever purpose you thought to use the primary key.

Comment: Why do you want to change the value of the primary key? And what do you do with all the foreign keys which reference your row?